# Bought two SSD drives. How should I use them for recording games with PlayClaw?

Tags: ssd

I just bought two 120 GB X-25 Mainstream SSD disks from Intel and I'm trying to figure out what the best setup would be for them.

I play games mainly and I also record in-game footage with PlayClaw/Fraps which strains your frames per second heavily. What would give me the most FPS? I was thinking of installing the OS (Windows 7) and the actual games on one of the SSD's and then recording the material to the other SSD. Would this be optimal or is there some better way?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this would be the best setup. Recording the data onto a different drive from where the game is fetching data would probably help diminish the performance impact on the game.

Still, I figure your biggest problem will be the encoding that the video goes through as it is being captures. I'm not familiar with the software you use, but I figure that it compresses the video somewhat when it saves it; you may want to look into the compression settings and lower them to avoid your CPU being chewed up by the process.

Good luck!